# Multiple USERNAME_FIELD in django user model

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-users

My custom user model:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True,max_length=75)
    is_staff = models.IntegerField(default=False)
    is_active = models.IntegerField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=None)

    # Use default usermanager
    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

Is there a way to specify multiple `USERNAME_FIELD` ? Something like `['email','username']` so that users can login via email as well as username ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `USERNAME_FIELD` setting does not support a list. You could create a [custom authentication backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#authentication-backends) that tries to look up the user on the 'email' or 'username' fields.

```
from django.db.models import Q

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

MyUser = get_user_model()

class UsernameOrEmailBackend(object):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        try:
           # Try to fetch the user by searching the username or email field
            user = MyUser.objects.get(Q(username=username)|Q(email=username))
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except MyUser.DoesNotExist:
            # Run the default password hasher once to reduce the timing
            # difference between an existing and a non-existing user (#20760).
            MyUser().set_password(password)
```

Then, in your `settings.py` set `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` to your authentication backend:

```
 AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('path.to.UsernameOrEmailBackend,)\
```

Note that this solution isn't perfect. For example, password resets would only work with the field specified in your `USERNAME_FIELD` setting.

Comment: BEWARE that in the default django implementation, the `email` field is not unique...security, weirdness, etc AHOI.

Answer (score 11):

**We can do that by implementing our own Email authentication backend.**

You can do something like below:

**Step-1 Substite the custom User model in settings:**

Since we would not be using Django's default `User` model for authentication, we need to define our custom `MyUser` model in `settings.py`. Specify `MyUser` as the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in the project's settings.

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'
```

**Step-2 Write the logic for the custom authentication backend:**

To write our own authentication backend, we need to implement atleast two  methods i.e. `get_user(user_id)` and `authenticate(**credentials)`.

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import check_password

class MyEmailBackend(object):
    """
    Custom Email Backend to perform authentication via email
    """
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        my_user_model = get_user_model()
        try:
            user = my_user_model.objects.get(email=username)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user # return user on valid credentials
        except my_user_model.DoesNotExist:
            return None # return None if custom user model does not exist 
        except:
            return None # return None in case of other exceptions

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        my_user_model = get_user_model()
        try:
            return my_user_model.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except my_user_model.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

**Step-3 Specify the custom authentication backend in settings:**

After writing the custom authentication backend, specify this authentication backend in the `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` setting.

`AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` contains the list of authentication backends to be used. Django tries authenticating across all of its authentication backends. If the first authentication method fails, Django tries the second one, and so on, until all backends have been attempted.

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'my_app.backends.MyEmailBackend', # our custom authentication backend
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend' # fallback to default authentication backend if first fails 
    )
```

If authentication via `MyEmailBackend` fails i.e user could not be authenticated via `email`, then we use the Django's default authentication `ModelBackend` which will try to authenticate via `username` field of `MyUser` model.

Comment: I created similar custom authentication backend now I want to pass email and phone number fields also while log in to this method. But I get only username and password field kwargs is blank Any Idea how to get all fields?

Comment: You don't need the `from django.contrib.auth.models import check_password` it is already a property of the  `auth_user_model` object. Otherwise nice solution.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot have more than one field defined in `USERNAME_FIELD`.

One option would be to write your own custom login to check for both fields yourself. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/

i.e. change the backend to your own. `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` then write an authenticate method and check the username on both fields in the DB.

PS you may want to use `unique_together` on your model so you don't run into problems.

Another option would be to use the actual field `username` to store both string and email.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, not out-of-the box.

The auth contrib module asserts that the USERNAME_FIELD value is mono-valued.

See https://github.com/django/django/search?q=USERNAME_FIELD

If you want to have a multi-valued USERNAME_FIELD, you will either have to write the corresponding logic or to find a package that allow it.