# Custom Authentication Backend in Django

Tags: django, authentication

How to write a custom authentication backend in Django taking scenario as Phone Number & OTP(One-Time Password) to authenticate against each user.

How to authenticate each user in form of multiple conditions.

1. If email is verified and password exist ( authenticate using email and password).
2. If phone is verified and exist( authenticate using phone and otp or if password exist then auth using phone and password).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to extend user model, here I leave you this page and you can choose which of them is better for you https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html

Comment: I have been already using a custom user model but specifying email as my username using AbstractBaseUser. My condition is how can i authenticate using email or phone. If email then get password to authenticate or if phone then send otp message or phone with password to authenticate. I want to authenticate user based on E-MAIL or PHONE NUMBER.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31370118/multiple-username-field-in-django-user-model maybe this help, of course you can add more logic according what you need, for example if PHONE NUMBER is verified

Comment: The above example is great. But how to authenticate a phone number if password is not present and we have to send an otp to authenticate that user. Can you explain me how to solve this flow.

Comment: well you can call a function setting a temporary password, anyway your question is too broad. Read this maybe can help you https://django-otp-official.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 3):

```
from django.contrib.auth import backends, get_user_model
from django.db.models import Q

class AuthenticationBackend(backends.ModelBackend):
"""
Custom authentication Backend for login using email,phone,username 
with password
"""

def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
    usermodel = get_user_model()
    try:
        user = usermodel.objects.get(
            Q(username__iexact=username) | Q(email__iexact=username) | Q(phone__iexact=username)

        if user.check_password(password):
            return user
    except usermodel.DoesNotExist:
        pass
```

For you have to specify the authclass in settings.py

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'applications.accounts.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)

Comment: Hey Nakul, can you provide the code for using email and password or phone with otp or phone with password.

Comment: and you can combine this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560182/django-authentication-without-a-password]  to check with otp

Comment: If you are satisfied with my code then can you mark this aswer

Comment: If you can combine the otp logic in the above provided code then it would be a great help. I'm actually new to Django so i'm little bit confused.

Comment: We will get the relevant user from the authenticate function. That is the main idea of authenticate. I can't give an exact code unless I get the exact logic you have implemented there. You can add necessary changes to the filter and get the verified user. Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks. Let me try it. If i face any problem i will reach you again.