# Django 2 login with email address, phone number or username

Tags: django, python-3.x, authentication, registration

What is the best way to implement django 2 login and registration like instagram.com. user can register with username and email or phone and password. after register user can login with email address, phone number or username.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31370118/multiple-username-field-in-django-user-model

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Hmm look like Implementing this is the only way to do this. def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None): Is there are any security issue implement this ?

Comment: None is there as default value. Authentication will fail if either value is None. So no security issues.

Answer (score 0):

A great thing about Django is that it comes with a User model already. You just have to apply it to your site.

Check out the user documentation [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/auth/)

This will give you all the fields you can use, and how to make a member style website

Comment: Thank you for your reply. yes i using this user model but Django USERNAME_FIELD  only can use one field. i need use login username field as a email, phone or username.